# Book with at least two boys trapped in an old house being pursued by Lovecraftian beings who were documented in family archives and/or an RPG

Tags: story-identification, novel, cthulhu-mythos

I read this as a Kindle book, probably at least 5 years ago, but probably not more than 10. I think I may have received the book free as a promotional item, and plan to try plumbing through my history and the email address I use to send Kindle files to my phone when not purchased through Amazon. I only finished the first few chapters of the book before I was interrupted, probably by another book I planned to read. There are at least two protagonists, both young boys, probably around middle school age. If I recall correctly, one belonged to a family with old money partially tied to a roleplaying game they put out about Eldritch horrors and the second was a fan of said game, seeking out the first boy at school for that reason.

In the part I read, the two boys were at the first boy's house when they started being attacked by creatures from the RPG books, which it turns out are based on documents in this family's archives. They initially deal with the incursion by turning on the floodlights tied to the house's security system. When those fail, I remember them taking down one of the creatures with a barbecue fork tied into the house mains. I'm not certain whether the first child's parents were missing, or just not there that night, but it's just the boys alone in the house that night.

If I recall correctly, the book had the first boy's name in the title, something like *Johnny Eldritch and the Creatures of Horror*, but I may be entirely offbase there. I think the book was written for kids, although the horror of the eldritch attackers was not played down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder if this is [*Billy Lovecraft Saves the World*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23530037-billy-lovecraft-saves-the-world) (2014) by "Billy Lovecraft."  It has a [Kindle edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00PKJHMFC), and one of the reviewers notes they received a free ebook for a review.  The reviews note the RPG aspect:

> Billy Lovecraft is 12-years old. His parents are killed in a plane crash caused by a terrifying creature. His parents were **famous for creating a popular role playing game** based upon their explorations of the mysteries of ancient and strange out-of-this-world creatures.
>
> <sub>[Goodreads review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1105030233?book_show_action=true&from_review_page=1)</sub>

Billy's parents (who were killed by a Shoggoth just before the start of the story) have an extensive collection:

> Even as the plot becomes more fantastic; even when Billy takes the gang on a tour of the **family home subbasement and its complete collection of Lovecraft artifacts**; even as the monsters multiply and the threat grows[...]
>
> <sub>[Another review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1123567932?book_show_action=true&from_review_page=1)</sub>

I can't find any specific details of how they deal with the monsters, and it appears there are more than 2 kids involved, but the rest seems to fit.

Comment: That's in my library and rereading it, it fits! Thank you.